# How to fill a list of vectors that change, with a sequence of numbers in R

Tags: r, list, for-loop, vector, sequence

Hello to this amazing community that makes our life easier.
Here goes.

I have a vector of numbers

```
set.seed(1)
numbers=sort(rnorm(35))
```

numbers

-2.21469989  -1.98935170  -1.47075238  -1.37705956  -0.83562861  -0.82046838 -0.62645381  -0.62124058  -0.47815006  -0.30538839  -0.15579551  -0.10278773 -0.05612874  -0.05380504  -0.04493361  -0.01619026  0.07456498   0.18364332  0.32950777   0.38767161   0.38984324   0.41794156   0.48742905   0.57578135
0.59390132   0.61982575   0.73832471   0.78213630   0.82122120   0.91897737  0.94383621   1.12493092   1.35867955   1.51178117   1.59528080

the numbers do not matter cause they change every time.
I need to fill those numbers into two vectors, lets call them A and B where A is stable, but B changes depending on some parameters.
I made B a list of vectors becoming for example B[1] and B[2].
depending on vector J.
So if vector J is

```
J=c(3,4,5,5)#example
```

B will be a list of 4 vectors (length of J), taking values from the vector "numbers", according to J.
Starting were A finished,with the next 3 numbers,then next 4 numbers, then next 5 numbers,and next the final 5 numbers, respectively.

I dont have a problem filling A as I am simply saying:

```
A=c(numbers[1:(6*3)])#takes all the values from -2.21469989 up to 0.18364332
```

My problem is filling B's, each one with the rest of the sequence each time.
I know I need a loop, something like

```
 B=list()
 J=c(3,4,5,5)#example with four vectors for B

    for (i in 1:4)
    {
      B[[i]]=c(?)
    }
```

I dont know how to proceed in order for my B's to take the rest of numbers 
from 0.32950777 to 1.59528080

can you please help?
The end result for this example, should be:

```
B[1]=c(0.32950777 , 0.38767161 , 0.38984324)
B[2]=c(0.41794156 , 0.48742905 , 0.57578135 , 0.59390132)
B[3]=c(0.61982575 , 0.73832471 , 0.78213630 , 0.82122120 , 0.91897737)
B[4]=c( 0.94383621 , 1.12493092 , 1.35867955 , 1.51178117  1.59528080)
```

Comment: B is a vector and then a list of vectors within the same paragraph..?

Comment: Why is the length of `B[4]` = 6?  From vector `J` I would expect the length of `B[4]` would be 5.  Also, the last element of `B[3]` appears to overlap `B[4]`

Comment: like this?? `J=c(3,4,5,5) ; sq <- rep(1:length(J), J ) ; b <- split(numbers[1:length(sq)], sq) `

Comment: @user20650 Yes, I think that's the idea, though the first 18 `numbers` were already "used" on A, so `B = split(numbers[-(1:18)], rep(seq_along(J),J) )`

Comment: ah cheers Frank, makes sense... i was wondering about the output

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade from comment... thanks to Frank for help.

You can use `rep` to generate a sequence of groups/indices to `split` you vector

```
# vector of positions
J <- c(3,4,5,5)

# create grouping variables
sq <- rep(1:length(J), J ) 

# split your vector
b <- split(numbers[-(1:18)], sq)
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I needed.I edited the output cause it was indedd five numbers in B[4]